# Want to store profiles in Qt, use SQLite or something else?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, orm, activerecord

I want to store some settings for different profiles of what a "task" does.

I know in .NET there's a nice ORM is there something like that or an Active Record or whatever?   I know writing a bunch of SQL will be fun

Comment: Are these profile specific to an instance of the application, a user, or global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to agree with Micheal E and say that you can use QJson, but no you don't have to manage serialization. QJson has a QObject->QJson serializer/deserialzer. So as long as all your relevant data is exposed via Q_PROPERTY QJson can grab it and write/read it to/from the disk.

Examples here: http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage.html

From there you can simply dump the data into a file.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to serialize objects to JSON with [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/).  You still need to manage serialization, but it could well be a lot simpler if you don't need sophisticated query capabilities.